# Check if process is running, if not start it

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter, ratchet

I'm using Ratchet, a Node js application and ZeroMq in my codeigniter based php application.

In my admin dashboard, I want to be able to see if the socket is running and also if my node js app is running. If it's down, I need to be able to put it back online.

I know I can use php's `exec` for putting it back online, but as soon as the script finish, so does the command line.

How can I achieve this? Something like:

Ratchet: Status online (Stop, Start, Restart)
Node service: Status online (Stop, Start, Restart)
ZeroMq: Status online (Stop, Start, Restart)

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by `but as soon as the script finish, so does the command line.`

Comment: i mean, if you run something like exec("node main.js");
it will open it and close it. Also i dont know how to control if its running or not

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of solutions including with `fsockopen()` to check if port is open...

But the only working solution is to check if node js application process is on with for argument the application file. If not I use `exec` to run it permanently (with `&` argument) and putting output in a logfile (in the same folder of the node app).

```
$node       = '/usr/bin/node';
$base       = '/path/to/your/app';
$appfile    = 'my_app.js';
$logfile    = 'my_app.log';
$proc       = explode("\n", trim(shell_exec(" ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $appfile")));
if ($proc[0] == '') {
    exec("$node $base/$appfile >> $base/$logfile &");
}
```

It's working fine and **running the node server only once**.

EDIT : Minimalist PHP code version :

```
if(trim(shell_exec('ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep app.js')))=='') {
    exec('node /path/to/app.js >> /path/to/app.log &');
}
```